# Javascript page redirection and session

Tags: javascript, session

I have signup javascript function. Is it correct to redirect to the user(private page of the user) through windiw.location function? Will it work inside the session scope? Will it append the httpcookie while redirecting the request?

```
function signup()
    {

        var uName = document.forms[0].email.value;
        var pass = document.forms[0].password.value;

        var xmlhttp;
        var response;
        var url = "/v2/application/userlogin?fromClient=web&"+"email="+uName+"&password="+pass;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                response =  xmlhttp.responseText;
                //alert(response);
                window.location = "/web/jsp/index.jsp?fromClient=web";

            } else {
                        //document.getElementById("mainWindow").innerHTML = "Loading...";
                        //alert("loding");
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();


        //alert(response);

    }
```

Comment: If you have cookie-based sessions then every page load should automatically include the session cookie and be within the session.  Setting location.href is just a way of triggering a page load so it should work.  You should of course have a (preferably server-side) check on the private page that the user is logged in in case someone comes directly there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly acceptable to redirect from within the ajax callback. However, when the protected page is requested, on the server side you must ensure the user has an authenticated session before you display the protected content.

> Will it append the httpcookie while redirecting the request?

If the server response included a new cookie, then yes it will be sent when the `window.location` request ocurrs.

Side note: you should URL encode the user input in the URL using `encodeURIComponent()` to avoid special characters from breaking the URL encoded format:

```
var url = "/v2/application/userlogin?fromClient=web&email="+ encodeURIComponent(uName)+"&password="+encodeURIComponent(pass);
```